# Unable to locate grandchild elements of the same grandparent using Protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

Using Protractor, my goal is to click on the update button given the name value, which is unique.

```
<div class="Employee">
  <div class="address">
    <button class="street" value="update"/>
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <div class="name" value="Joe Smith"/> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Employee">
  <div class="address">
    <button class="street" value="update"/>
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <div class="name" value="Jane Smith"/> 
  </div>
</div>
```

So have tried looking for all 'Employee' elements to find all parents and then filtering to find which 'Employee' element has the particular child with value of 'Jane Smith'.  Then use that parent element to click the Update button.

```
element.all(by.css('[class="Employee"]')).filter(function (elem,index) {
  if(elem.element(by.css('[value="Jane Smith"]')).isPresent()){  
    return elem
  }
}).then(function (elem) {
  elem[0].element(by.css('[value="update"]')).click()
})
```

The problem is that in the 'if' statement, it is always equating to true and I am not sure why.

Perhaps there is another approach to solving this without using xpaths as this environment is always changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to your if statement, it should look more like this:

```
elem.element(by.css('[value="Jane Smith"]')).isPresent())
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result) { } //true
        else { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `filter` very often with our app so kinda a shot in the dark, but I believe you need an additional `return` statement.  See if this works for you:

```
element.all(by.css('[class="Employee"]')).filter(function (elem,index) {
    return elem.element(by.css('[value="Jane Smith"]')).isPresent().then(function(val) {  
        return val == true;  // or val === true if you prefer
    });
}).then(function (items) {
    console.log(items.length) // just to check the number is what you expect
    items[0].element(by.css('[value="update"]')).click()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend [@Gunderson's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38465314/771848).

> The problem is that in the 'if' statement, it is always equating to true and I am not sure why.

This is because [`isPresent()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) method like almost everything in Protractor *returns a promise* which is "truthy" by default. You need to resolve the promise to actually get a real value.

Also, I would improve the locator and the way you the locating an inner element - you can use `first()` and simply *chain* the `element` call, no need for `then()` in this case:

```
$$(".Employee").filter(function (elem) {
    return elem.$('[value="Jane Smith"]').isPresent().then(function(isPresent) {  
        return isPresent;
    });
}).first().$('[value="update"]').click();
```

Make sure to study [Promises and the Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow) documentation to gain more understanding of the concept of promises and the control flow which is the under-the-hood mechanism maintaining the queue of promises and resolving them.

---

Note that you could've approach it with an [XPath expression](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath) and in a single line - though that is not quite readable, looking fragile and more difficult to maintain:

```
var updateButton = element(by.xpath("//div[@class='Employee' and div[@class='profile']/div[@class='name']/@value = 'Jane Smith']/div[@class='address']/button[@value='update']"));
updateButton.click();
```